# How to print a webpage from a Dart/polymer web app

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, printing-web-page

I am trying to print 'what I see' in my Dart+polymer web app. I am getting a blank page in the print preview (Windows). The Title is there, which I have removed using CSS (so there is a bit of reaction to my css! It's not totally dead).

I have tried a separate print style sheet for printing. I have also tried adding the following to my main css:

```
@media print { 
  body {
    font: 12pt Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
    color: #222222;
   line-height: 1.3;
}

header, footer{
  display: none;
}
@page{
 margin: 0.5cm;
} 
}
```

and separating out the @media screen{}

I have polymer buttons etc, and many elements (tables, lists, canvas...) dynamically added using code, and also Polymer templates + data binding. I understand I only have to change items that need to be, to overwrite existing styles.

So, is it possible to simply add some CSS to print? Do I have to do something with shadow dom?

Thanks

Cheers, Steve

Comment: Just curious, are you using the `unresolved` attribute on body? What happens if you remove that?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Just tried it - no effect.  All print preview shows is the warnings box at the bottom right (because I'm including my css too many times....for another discussion!). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for some hours until I thought of this:
- copy the content I want to print to a new window and print that window.

Now that's a little tricky because styles would be lost. (But basically, that's like the best way out.

code sample:

```
var prnWnd = window.open();
prnWnd.document.title = "Title of Printed Page"; //in case you print "headers"
$(document.querySelector('#head').cloneNode(true).innerHTML).appendTo(prnWnd.document.head);

$('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+location.origin+location.pathname+'includepathtoextra.css">').appendTo(prnWnd.document.head);

$(document.querySelector('#contentToPrint')).appendTo(prnWnd.document.body);
prnWnd.print(); // bring up the print dialog
prnWnd.close(); // close the print view once the print dialog is disposed
```

Comment: Looks like you are using jQuery. Are you really working with Dart? The question is about Polymer-Dart.

Comment: I'm using Polymer,with jquery embedded.